# I want treat `variable..'['..i..']'` as a indexing attempt

Tags: lua, lua-table, love2d

here my code blows up: `love.graphics.print(jugador..'['..i..']', i * 100, 10)` I tried `'jugador'..'['..i..']'`
so i want help to get this `jugador[1], jugador[2], jugador[n]` treated a an indexing attempt not a text or something else...

Comment: I can't tell if you want a value (`jugador[i]`) or a string (`'jugador['..i..']'`). If neither of those work, please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @luther i want the value "color" in 'n' of idexes (uhhh error edit sorry) this is fed into jugador[number of player]: 
jugadorbase      = {}
jugadorbase.x     = 100
jugadorbase.y     = 300
jugadorbase.vidas    = 4
jugadorbase.color    = 0, 1, 1 i want extract this for every player
jugadorbase.tamañox    = 20
etc (it dont fit)
like: jugador[1].color =>"0, 1, 1" and for contrast: jugador[2].color => "0.5, 1, 0.125"
Sorry for the weird reply i blame literally a blackout

Comment: I don't understand how that relates to what you wrote in your question. I can only reiterate my previous comment. Note that you can edit your question by clicking "Edit".

Comment: anyway i found another way (function getKey(table)), but thx by ur time, and not getting annoyed by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
love.graphics.print(jugador[i], i * 100, 10)
```

is what you want, or based on your description in the comments

```
local color = jugador[i].color
local str = color[1] .. ", " .. color[2] .. ", " .. color[3]
love.graphics.print(str, i * 100, 10)
```

You will also need to understand loops [loops](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html).

As luther said, please provide a minimal example and edit your question with the important additional information given in your comment.